# Switch apache version fom console (WAMP)

Tags: php, apache, cmd, console, wampserver

I'm working with a program that allows me change the php and apache version from console and just can't find a way to switch from the version `2.9` to `2.4.16`. If I switch the version everything works perfectly but I need a way to do it automatically.

Comment: Why do you need to do it Automatically. And what do you mean by automatically?

Comment: @RiggsFolly by the console, I need a command to switch the version. And I need it because is required for the program that Im building.

Comment: Do you mean you want to run PHP CLI Scripts with different versions of PHP?